# dbus_connection_send_with_reply timeout

Tags: c, linux, dbus

When calling `dbus_connection_send_with_reply` through the D-Bus C API in Linux, I pass in a timeout of 1000ms, but the timeout never occurs when the receiving application doesn't reply.

If the receiving application does send a reply then this is received correctly.

Could this be due to the way that I'm servicing libdbus?

I am calling `dbus_connection_dispatch` and `dbus_connection_dispatch` periodically for servicing.

Thanks

Comment: A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help...

Answer (score 1):

It is **highly** recommended that you use a D-Bus library *other* than libdbus, as libdbus is fiddly to use correctly, as you are finding. If possible, use [GDBus](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html) or [QtDBus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html) instead, as they are much higher-level bindings which are easier to use. If you need a lower-level binding, [sd-bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-bus.html) is more modern than libdbus.

If you use GDBus, you can use [GMainLoop](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) to implement a main loop to handle timeouts, and set the timeout period with `g_dbus_proxy_set_default_timeout()` or in the arguments to individual `g_dbus_proxy_call()` calls. If you use sd-bus, you can use [sd-event](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-event.html#).